# Bignum calculations in python gives wrong output

Tags: python-3.x, bignum

I know that python 3.x supports bignum natively..
But it shows wired output for some set of numbers

```
r = 1152500320511525003205
x = 23
y = r/x
mod = r%x  # zero
print ( y*x == r) # False
```

The last statement shall give out true as `x` divides `r` in `r%x` equals `0`
So the question, is there something I miss here ?

---

Environment details :
Python 3.6.0
Linux Arch 4.9.7-1-ARCH x86_64 GNU/Linux

Note : I have  checked the calculations using multiple online big num calculators and also my own one which I wrote.
They all give different value than python

Comment: you missed integer division: `r//x`. People, don't answer more, looking for duplicate... don't hesitate to upvote the linked answer :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, The answer was so simple and I did vote up...
What annoyed me that I didn't get the linked question in search grrr.

Comment: thanks for the UV. Don't worry about the duplicates. They're OK most of the time. Since you searched and found nothing, writing a question with a different wording increases the chance that someone finds the answer next time, either by original question or duplicate.